# Drupal commerce display VAT exclusive unit price & subtotal for line item in cart and order

Tags: commerce

I has a VAT tax for my products. It's a B2B site so we only show Tax exclusive price to customers. Even in cart and order. The VAT only show in the cart & order bottom just as the Drupal commerce original one.

My problem is I can not find a way to show the VAT exclusive price in the cart views. There is no option for that. The line item unit price field 'formatted amount' is showing VAT included price. 'formatted amount with components' is showing a price table like this:

```
Subtotal    $16.50 AUD
GST $1.65 AUD
Unit price  $18.15 AUD
```

That's not what I want. How can I only show the the price exclude the VAT tax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I find this module: [Commerce price by components](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_components)

This is perfect for my requirement.

> Extension to Drupal commerce that provides a price formatter to enable/disable price components such as discounts or taxes when
>   displaying prices. This gives the admin absolute control over which
>   components should be displayed and which shouldn't. It also provides
>   two Views handlers to display/hide price components in cart totals and
>   order totals. Additionally it has basic rules support that gives to
>   the commerce administrators the ability to do conditions using price
>   components such as discounts or taxes and react accordingly.
>
> Example use case
>
> If you want to customize your cart or checkout views, you may want to
>   display prices with taxes and without discounts (or viceversa) in your
>   line items but the total amount should be displayed. Then you enable
>   this module and choose at formatter level (both display fields and
>   views) which components you want to hide or display.

[image]